# Update Subversion repository to mirror working copy, alterations included

Tags: svn

I am attempting to perform backups using Subversion but running into trouble when it comes to ensuring the folder I want to update is in sync with my Subversion repo directory.

See, stuff is constantly changed - folders removed, new content added etc. And this is the problem - how can I update to my Subversion repo and have Subversion automatically recognise what's changed?

Basically, the only way I can get everything to mirror my working copy without any errors is to sacrifice the differencing feature (and all previous backups) of Subversion by doing the following:

1. checking out a directory from my subversion repo - let's call is x-folder
2. svn delete the contents of the directory
3. svn commit
4. copy the data I wish to update (my new, fresh, slightly altered data) to Subversion into x-folder
5. svn add
6. svn commit

I played with some other scenarios but ran into other problems.

So, how exactly can I use Subversion to store a running backup? Am I missing something completely obvious?

Answer (score 0):

> how exactly can I use Subversion to store a running backup?

in no way

> Am I missing something completely obvious?

Yes. Subversion (and any other VCS) is **not backup-system**, **must not be used** as backup's replacement

**If** you want for *some folder* store it new state in Subversion repository, you can (while it terribly ugly)

- Convert this folder into Working Copy of `Somepath` in `Somerepo`
- use any tool for detecting changes inside WC
- in case of changes - run `svn commit -m "SOME EXPLANATION HERE"`

Comment: The crucial part is this: use any tool for detecting changes inside WC. I need a script or tool which goes through my Working Copy and detects any files OR folders that have been deleted and then add new content. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PuffinMaster - keyword is "FAM", URLs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx http://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/